# How to make jQueryUI datepicker permanently expanded

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datepicker

I want to make a datepicker which is always expanded; how can I do it?

Comment: You could start by telling us *which* datepicker.

Comment: jquery datepicker, from jquery-1.4.2.js

Comment: You mean the [jQuery *UI* widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)? jQuery !== jQuery UI, please be careful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can set the focus on that field, and that should open up the datepicker.  It also supports a "show" option.  Maybe look into that.

Comment: Ok, but what do do when I have two datepickers, and I want to have them expanded all the time. I have not found any hints on the jqueryui website so far for this.